# javascript inheritFrom Vs Prototype

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype-programming

I am wondering whats the difference between inheritFrom and the prototype when defining inheritance in Javascript.

```
function classA{}
classA.name="abc";
classA.functionName=function(){
alert("Function Name Alert");
}
function classB{ }
```

Whats the difference in the below codes?

```
classB.prototype=classA();
```

and

```
classB.prototype.inheritFrom(classA);
```

Comment: Where does inheritFrom come from ?

Comment: Searching for inhertFrom, I've found this: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaScript/0500__Object-Oriented/UsinginheritFrommethodfromzInheritLibrary.htm

Comment: it comes from zinherit library...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`B.prototype.inheritFrom(A)` is not standard JavaScript, whereas `B.prototype = new A` is standard JavaScript. I suggest learning the ins and outs of JavaScript and embracing the prototype. You'll be better off for knowing it. It's really not too difficult:

```
function A(){}
function B(){}
B.prototype = new A;
b = new B;
console.log(b instanceof B, b instanceof A);
//-> true, true
```